# WS security to SOAP request header from java client

Tags: soap, java

I am trying to connect to Salesforce from java client using SOAP api. All the examples in the documentation point to a using ConnectorConfig class to connect from java. However I need to set wsse:security header in my request, could not find any example of a custom SOAP header. I see there is a com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection class and looking for any examples on how to use it. Did anyone use "com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection" in java code?

Comment: SF does not support WS-Security out of the box. You deleted the Q&A where it was explained it to you that if you're going through a non-SF proxy that needs WS-Security, you'll need to ask this question on another forum such as StackOverflow (SO).

Comment: Thank you idenigral!